# Эту фразу надо сбоку / с боку рисунка подписать

Tags: орфография

А здесь надо слитно или раздельно?

> Эту фразу надо сбоку / с боку рисунка подписать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Правильно:

*Эту фразу надо **сбоку рисунка** подписать.*

***Сбоку*** — наречный предлог, управление Р.п.

Нормировано только **слитное** написание наречия и наречного предлога.

Русский орфографический словарь:

**СБОКУ, нареч. и предлог** (конверт сбоку разорван; он стоял сбоку стола), но сущ. с боку и с бока (больного надо перевернуть с боку на спину).

2. Возможно ли **раздельное** написание?  Если только очень **постараться,** например:

*Эту фразу перенесите  **с боку рисунка** на его верхнюю часть*.

Здесь **предметное** значение существительного.